# Firebase JSON: Need to access child, but each child again has more child

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Root has a child chat. In Chat we have chats saved of different users (in this case they are aseed, aseed2 and aseed3. I need to display names of user in a list view (show aseed, aseed2 and aseed3 in a list).

**Here is the JSON**

```
{
 "chat" : {
    "aseed" : {
      "-KQC94Spu5JdJRbjnBh_" : {
        "author" : "JavaUser72599",
        "message" : "ggf"
      },
      "-KQC98gR9vKOyOAtKrS5" : {
        "author" : "JavaUser72599",
        "message" : "dhdh"
      }
    },
    "aseed3" : {
      "-KQCBw_ldkfhVG643eFH" : {
        "author" : "aseed3",
        "message" : "aseed"
      },
      "-KQCBxQJXq8rIqkHvA4r" : {
        "author" : "aseed3",
        "message" : "ok"
      },
      "-KQCC30HjSsHWSot9MNu" : {
        "author" : "aseed3",
        "message" : "hi"
      }
    },
    "aseed2" : {
      "-KQCC0-q6Do67PiFXXcP" : {
        "author" : "aseed2",
        "message" : "ok ok"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The demo project Android Chat shows how to read final data in the leaves.

Comment: show your current code.

Comment: explain your question with example code

Comment: Using this - https://github.com/firebase/AndroidChat 
with slight moditifications I create these chat scripts where chat scripts are saved in seperate childs, according to username. I don't have code to access the names now (like aseed, aseed2, aseed3) to display it in list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I see it, you need to access the key of that particular DataSnapshot node. What you could do is, as soon as you get access to the aseed, aseed2.. nodes(which would probably be inside a for loop), you could just get the key for every child and inflate a ListView with it.

The `DataSnapshot` element has a method called `getKey().`

Here's the documentation. [DataSnapshot getKey() Method](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DataSnapshot.html#getKey())

Answer (score 0):

You can get jsonobject then get names which will return JSONArray. 
Code:

```
String jsonstr = json;//This is the JSON string

JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(jsonstr);
JSONObject chat = jo.getJSONObject("chat");
JSONArray jsonNames = chat.names();
String[] names = null;
for(i=0; i < jsonNames.length();i++)
    names[i] = jsonNames.get(i);
```

Now use this names array anywhere you want.